# Convert plugin to ng-directive

Tags: angularjs, plugins, angularjs-directive, coffeescript

This should be straightforward, but I'm missing something.

I am using the [greensock draggable animation library](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/), grunt, bower, npm, etc.

`bower.json` dependencies:

[image]

grunt (in CoffeeScript), bower_concat main files: because the draggable component isn't listed in the tween file in greensock's bower.json:

[image]

my directive, in CoffeeScript:

[image]

My jasmine test is saying it can't find the reference to Draggable.js in my compiled JS.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Draggable in file:///Users/ari.picker/apps/LightHouse/lighthouse/lighthouse-ui/.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/temp/compiled-coffee/src/lessons/panes-directives/greensockDraggable.js (line 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try changing `"greensock"` to `"gsap"`in your grunt file.</strike>

Including TweenMax with the plugins/utils seems to work.

```
mainFiles: {
  "greensock": ["src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js", "src/uncompressed/utils/Draggable.js"]
}
```

Comment: Why should this change work? Is `greensock` no longer valid, or was it never valid?

Comment: The package is named `gsap` so I thought that was the issue, but I was wrong. I corrected my mistake.